# Filtro de busqueda

Tags: ajax, laravel

Buenas, tengo una especie de problema, cuando intento filtrar los usuarios, en si, me da dos errores ambos relacionados con la paginación.

- El primero es que cuando cambiamos de pagina los campos se envían vacíos por lo que al cambiar de pagina vuelven todos los datos del usuario como si no hubiéramos aplicado el filtro.
- El segundo error consiste en que el ajax me renderiza solo la section users sin embargo cambia toda la página no solo la sección que quiero, es decir me borra la sección de filtro, entiendo que sea por el rendersection

¿hay alguna forma de especificar que renderize una section en específico dentro de un div específico?

[image: Funcion del filtro de usuario]

[image: Vista de usuario]

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: en lo personal la paginacion de laravel es lo unico que no me agrada de él, ya que para cada pagina debe de hacer (volver a hacer) la consulta y eso no es bueno, te recomiendo utilizar datatables (https://datatables.net/) el cual te dara muchos beneficios como la paginacion, el filtrado o buscado y ademas el ordenar depende a las columnas

Comment: @Shassain Si tienes 5.000 registros no es una buena idea Datatables, incluso con menos, no veo porque ajax no es una buena opción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este caso es muy comun, el "->paginate()" que usa eloquent en laravel lo que nos genera son links a la misma pagina pero agregando un "?page=n", donde "n" es el numero de pagina, pero como bien digo, es un link y por tanto una recarga de pagina entera y perdida de datos.
Pero tengo una buena noticia para ti, eso se puede editar, aunque es un poco costoso. Debes rellenar el link con los datos del filtro, para que en el enlace que te crea la paginación.

```
{{ $datos->appends('filter'=>'someValue')->links() }}
{{ $datos->fragment('someValue')->links() }}
```

Igualmente, esto es frustrante y te quitara mucho tiempo (vas a reinventar la rueda), por lo que te recomiendo usar librerías ya creadas (https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter) o ver un tutorial como http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-jquery-ajax-pagination-example-from-scratchexample.html